# How to Change logo on the specific page of website in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I m working on a website in wordpress.

I searched for a problem that i want a different logo in one page of my site using any plugin but i didn't find a satisfactory solution.

Kindly someone tell me how can i do this that main logo should be appear on the whole site but secondary logo should appear on one page of my site

Comment: you can create a different header for that page only.. In that header u can change the color logo.. and then go to page, change the header in the get_header();

Comment: Please share header.php file (place where logo is shown) from your theme so we can help.

Comment: my theme not allowing me to do this.i m not using elementor.

Comment: header.php is not showing in my theme editor

Answer (score 0):

if you know wordpress developement, you can use conditional tags. [ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is_page()` method to check which page you are in and change the logo accordingly.

So, in the header or where ever your logo is displayed, you will do it like this:

```
<?php
//Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID = 42, or post_name is "about-me", or post_title is "About Me And Joe".
if(is_page( array( 42, 'about-me', 'About Me And Joe' ) ) )
{
    //display the secondary logo
}
else
{
    //display the main logo
}
```

Of course I'm assuming here that the page you want it to be different is a WordPress `page`

If it's a listing page or a single post page then you can use different methods of checking. All of which are described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

Comment: in the if condition what i have to write. Should i have to write the code background: url(logo.gif");

Answer (score 0):

Please insert this code to your header.php file.

```
$ss = $wp_query->post->post_title;
                    if($ss == 'your page name'){
                        echo '<img src="/your-new-logo.png" />';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<img src="/your-current-logo.png" />';
                    }
```

Comment: i am not getting the header.php file.. in the theme editor just function.php file is showing :-|